# JODConverter & LibreOffice: convert doc to html with embedded images

Tags: java, libreoffice, jodconverter

I'm converting doc/docx files to html with JODConverter library(4.2.2) and LibreOffice (6.2). What I need is to save images as embedded in html file, but by default it saving in separate files.

In order to do that with LibreOffice command line interface i'm using:

```
soffice --convert-to html:HTML:EmbedImages example.docx
```

I'm wondering if there any way to pass option **EmbedImages** through JODConverter library?

My java code:

```
LocalConverter
    .make()
    .convert(new FileInputStream(docFile))
    .as(DefaultDocumentFormatRegistry.getFormatByMediaType(file.getMediaType().getName()))
    .to(htmlTempFile)
    .as(DefaultDocumentFormatRegistry.HTML)
    .execute();
```

Comment: Turning an HTML with external images to embedded images is really simple, reading all bytes, 1 call, Base64 bytes-to-text, 1 call, data url in tag/css (mime type png/jpeg).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would work:

```java
final DocumentFormat format =
    DocumentFormat.builder()
        .from(DefaultDocumentFormatRegistry.HTML)
        .storeProperty(DocumentFamily.TEXT, "FilterOptions", "EmbedImages")
        .build();

LocalConverter
    .make()
    .convert(new FileInputStream(docFile))
    .as(DefaultDocumentFormatRegistry.getFormatByMediaType(file.getMediaType().getName()))
    .to(htmlTempFile)
    .as(format)
    .execute();
```

Comment: Doing the same still not working for me. It is still creating separate images

Comment: @DhirenSolanki Can you provide more detail ?? Which version are you using ? Can you create a sample project and share it ? You can also open an issue on github with a sample project if you can easily reproduce the problem.